# Undefined variable: films (View: C:\xampp2\htdocs\laravel5\resources\views\create.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am beginning in the field of laravel,
I can not access my form, can you help me?

The controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Sex;
use App\Film;
use App\Personnage;

class CreateController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $films = Film::all();
    return View('create', compact('films'));
  }
}
```

the views

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Film</label>
          <select multiple name="film[]" type="select" value="['multipe' => true]"  class="form-control">
            @foreach ($films as $value)
            <option value="{{{$value->id}}}">{{{$film->film}}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
```

The Routes

```
Route::get('/create', 'PersoController@create');
Route::post('/perso/insert', 'PersoController@insertOne');

Route::get('/', 'BaseController@index');
Route::get('/perso/delete/{id}', 'PersoController@deleteOne');

Route::get('/perso/update/{id}', 'PersoController@updateOne');
Route::post('/perso/update', 'PersoController@updateOneAction');
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't have `CreateController` in the routes list, so I guess you're just executing some other method, but not `CreateController@index`

Comment: you mean "undefined variable `film`" not `films` ?

Comment: Yes that was it, I really did not see, thank you :)

Comment: @MartyHemart what was "it"? :)

Comment: Route::get ('/ create', 'PersoController @ create'); qu'il était nécessaire de changer -> Route :: get ('/ create', 'CreateController @ index');

Answer (score 1):

You potentially have an undefined variable named `film` in your view.

You are iterating `$films as $value` .. you then try to use `$film->film` in that loop. I would imaging you want `$value->film`.

Answer (score 0):

Put following code

```
$films = Film::all();
return View('create',['films'=>$films]);
```

Above code will work for your blade code like this

```
@foreach ($films as $value)
<option value="{{{$value->id}}}">{{{$value->film}}}</option>
```

Assuming that your routes along with controllers are correct.

Comment: `view('create', compact('films'))` is the same thing as `view('create', ['films' => $films])` in this case

Comment: if so then no need of this answer, will delete

Comment: not in all cases, but in this case it is the same as `$films` has been defined, so `compact` will pull it in .. if `$films` wasn't defined compact would skip it and it would be an empty array being passed, that would be different ... and potentially something to watch out for when using `compact`

Comment: np .. you are also correcting that loop, which is actually where the error seems like it would come from, so i wouldn't delete this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161238/discussion-between-lagbox-and-webdev).

Comment: Thanks, members like you on stackoverflow make this site better and better. Liked Optimism and teaching ability !!!!!